# Amazon ETC2 outputs directory listing instead of the index page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, facebook-opengraph, ipv6

I'm not very good when it comes to setting up a server on Amazon but together with a friend I set up an EC2 with cPanel and IPv6 enabled. The website is http://tomeofheroes.com . The issue I'm having is that when I'm trying to post this website on a social platform I get a directory listing instead of the actual index page. I have setup all the proper og tags so that's not the issue.

This is the facebook developer link for example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tomeofheroes.com%2F

Here are my og tags:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Tome of Heroes">
<meta property="og:description" content="Competitive & High Skill-Cap PvP on your mobile device.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.tomeofheroes.com/images/og_image.png">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.tomeofheroes.com/">

<meta name="twitter:title" content="Tome of Heroes">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Competitive & High Skill-Cap PvP on your mobile device.">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://www.tomeofheroes.com/images/og_image.png">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="http://tomeofheroes.com/images/twitter_card.png">

<meta name="twitter:site" content="@TomeOfHeroes">
```

Again, I'm not very experienced when it comes to setting up the server properly but as far as I can tell it seems to work fine, it just doesn't work on social networks. In any case, if someone has any idea of what's wrong, I'd really appreciate it! Please try and explain it in basic terms, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you recently change the IP address of the server?  The site loads fine.

Comment: no, I didn't... yeah it does seem to load fine.. but the facebook developer crawler doesn't go through for some reason :(